# How to get steam level and make a check if someone has at least steam level 2

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I've been thinking about this so much and made it but something is wrong I think in the code. Can you say me what's it? I'd appreciate it! :)

```
<?php
         $link = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetSteamLevel/v1/? 
         key=".$api_key."&steamid=".$user['steamid']);
$result = json_decode($link, true);
    $_SESSION['steam_level'] = $result['response']['player_level'];
       if(!$_SESSION['steam_level'] >=2 && $_SESSION['steam_level'] <=3000){
       exit(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'You must have steam level 2 at least.')));
    }   
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you please share what the result of the api is? I'd like to see the returned JSON.

Comment: Also can you detail what is wrong? What's the issue that makes you think something is wrong? Are there any errors?

Comment: {"response":{"player_level":11}} this is an output of a steam level

Comment: I don't see an error somewhere but it's not recognizing when I have how much steam level.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your if statement. It appears the issue is with the `!` (not) at the front of the first part of your `if` statement. Essentially, you were looking at someone who was within the parameters of your first condition but with the addition of the `!` was causing the whole statement to become false, thus not completing any of the actions within the `if` statement. If you added an `else` statement to your code it would have worked.

My code below, flipped it around. So essentially, my first statement is looking to see if the steam users level is between `2` and `3000`. If it is `exit("success")`, if not, show your error message.

```
<?php
  $link = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetSteamLevel/v1/? 
     key=".$api_key."&steamid=".$user['steamid']);
  $result = json_decode($link, true);
  $_SESSION['steam_level'] = $result['response']['player_level'];
  if($_SESSION['steam_level'] >= 2 && $_SESSION['steam_level'] <= 3000) {
    exit("success");
  } else {
    exit(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'You must have steam level 2 at least.')));
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't do the right thing I just pasted it. Like it doesn't know how much level I am I think.

Comment: It does know what level you are. You can test by removing the `IF` statements and printing `$result['response']['player_level']`. That will show what level you are.